# PineScript: Print the bar time in exchange timezone

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

In my pinescript (version:5), I am trying to add a label that will display the current bar's high, RSI and the bar closing time.

The time is coming in UTC. How can I convert it to GMT:5:30 or "Asia/Kolkata" timezone?

My code snippet is this:

```
if (ta.crossunder(rsi, rsiOSLimit))
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(high, "#") + ":" + str.tostring(rsi, "#") + ":" + str.format("{0,time,short}", time), color=color.black, textcolor=color.white, yloc= yloc.price)
```

I have tried out with this also, did not worked:

```
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(high, "#") + ":" + str.tostring(rsi, "#") + ":" + str.format("{0,time,short}", time_close(timeframe.period, syminfo.session, syminfo.timezone)), color=color.black, textcolor=color.white, yloc= yloc.price)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
//@version=5
strategy('Opening high/low', overlay=true)


//label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(time_close - timenow))


printTable(txt) =>
    var table t = table.new(position.middle_right, 1, 1)
    table.cell(t, 0, 0, txt, text_halign = text.align_right, bgcolor = color.yellow)

printTable(
  str.format("Last bar''s open time EXCHANGE: {0,date,HH:mm:ss yyyy.MM.dd}", time(timeframe.period, syminfo.session, syminfo.timezone)) +
  str.format("\nLast bar''s close time EXCHANGE: {0,date,HH:mm:ss yyyy.MM.dd}", time_close(timeframe.period, syminfo.session, syminfo.timezone)))
```

Result should be like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qld7r.png)